# Mocha's glob behaviour

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, glob

My directory follows this structure:

```
src
  /test
    - file-test.js
  - file.js
```

My Mocha script uses

```
mocha -R spec --recursive ./**/*-test.js
```

Which leads to the fantastical error of `Error: Cannot find module 'tap'`.

But peculiarly the following two options work

1. `mocha -R spec --recursive ./src/**/*-test.js`
2. Renaming `file-test.js` to `file.test.js` and using `mocha -R spec --recursive ./**/*.test.js`

But I have no idea why those two options work, and my original plan did not.

Comment: Just an idea, but can you try to escape the minus sign, like so `mocha -R spec --recursive ./**/*\-test.js`. Maybe even multiple times, once for bash, once for JS. Might rely on RegEx matching

Comment: @martinczerwi: I've tried the following two:

`"test": "mocha -R spec --recursive ./**/*\\-test.js"` and
`"test": "mocha -R spec --recursive ./**/*\\\\-test.js"`

which both give me a "Cannot resolve path" error

Comment: @Louis: That post did not help my problem. instead it leads to Cannot resolve path error

Comment: @user1778856 You should edit your question to make the issue reproducible, taking into account the answer on the other question. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this is a long shot, but the glob pattern must be between double quotes if this is an npm script: `mocha -R spec --recursive "./**/*-test.js"`. I had a similar error with mocha.

Comment: [Here's the open issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1115) requesting documentation of this in mochajs... This is the right answer, but I should mention that I've noticed a drastic slowdown using this method. Has this been other people's experience?

Comment: @chrisjlebron I don't remember having slowdown, but I always used mocha with this syntax as far as I can tell. My tests take less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a while back, but I've had a similar issue, if you specify a matching file pattern eg. `src/**/*.spec.js` then `--recursive` is apparently redundant https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005752
The above comment about escaping the path because npm uses "" double quotes should be correct I believe.
So instead of something like this: 
`mocha --recursive ./**/*-test.js`
This worked for me:
`mocha \"./**/*-test.js\"`

Hope that helped..