# How can I select all folders and subfolders any layers deep with custom file ending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, create-react-app, package.json

I made a React app using Create-React-App. I have a testing script in my React app's `package.json` like this:

```
"test": "node -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill **/*.test.js | tap-color",
```

This catches and executes the files in `src/` like `src/App.test.js`, but not `header.test.js` in `src/layout/header/header.test.js`. And what if I add even more layers of folders? Is there a regex that will catch all folders in `src/` and their subfolders no matter how nested with a file ending of `.test.js`?

**Edit:** I found [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005580/how-can-mocha-recursively-search-my-src-folder-for-a-specific-filename-pattern). According to that answer you would have to write:

```
"test": "node -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-color",
```

which unfortunately matches nothing for me. I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you refer to is not *especially* useful for your case. My answer there works because Mocha has been designed to pass the patterns you give to it to the [`glob` library](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for interpretation. So when you do `mocha 'src/app/**/*.tests.js'` the quotes prevent the shell from interpreting the pattern, Mocha gets `src/app/**/*.tests.js` as the first pattern given to it, which it gives to `glob` to get a list of files to actually run. Your case is different at least one crucial way: `glob` is not involved so there is nothing that can correctly interpret `**`.

Your first attempt is consistent with what happens when you are using a shell that does not understand `**`. It is interpreted exactly the same as `*`. So the shell interprets `**/*.test.js` as `*/*.test.js`, expands this pattern and passes the result to `node`.

In your second attempt, you quote the pattern but that does not help you because `node` does not do pattern interpretation. It tries to load a file at path `src/**/*.test.js`, *interpreted literally*. This is not what you want.

I'm not sure what the compatibility implication with Windows are, but you could replace `'src/**/*.test.js'` with `$(find src -type f -name '*.test.js')`. (See [the `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1p.html) for details.) At run-time, the shell will replace this with the result of the `find` command.

Or for greater simplicity, and less risk of platform issues creeping up, you could use [`babel-tap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-tap) like this:

```
babel-tap 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-color
```

If you use `babel-tap`, there's actually no need for using `find` because internally `babel-tap` calls on facilities that use the `glob` library to interpret the file names passed to it.

---

I've focused on the file pattern issue but I'm not seeing how what you're trying to do would work, even without the pattern issue. Consider this command, and assume that the files exist:

```
node -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill src/a.test.js src/b.test.js
```

This is not telling Node to run `src/a.test.js` and `src/b.test.js`. Rather, it tells node "run the script `src/a.test.js` and pass to it the parameter `src/b.test.js`". I've not used `tap` very much but I don't recall it working this way. Using `babel-tap` like I show above also avoids the problem here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Using `"test": "node -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill $(find src -type f -name '*.test.js') | tap-color",` works in that it finds the **first** file matching the pattern. But as you assumed, only runs the tests in the first file and skips the rest. (I think) I unfortunately can't use `babel-tap` since I'm using `RITEway` and that library imports and uses tape, so I have no control over the `test` function. Do you have any other idea how I could run all tests? Is there a way I could loop the test command until all files have been found?

Comment: Not familiar with RITEway. What I'd try is `node -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill ./node_modules/.bin/riteway 'src/**/*.test.js'`. (I've typed this off the top of my head. Watch out for typos and make sure the path to `riteway` is correct.) The change is just to pass the `riteway` script as the name of the script to run and give to it the glob pattern as argument. From the README of RITEway it seems that it supports glob patterns natively.

Comment: Holy cow, that works. Thank you so much, Louis, you helped me a lot. Having to run dozens of test suites manually after a refactor is tedious. No more! 