# Mocha run with recursive glob pattern does not run all tests on Mac

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, mocha.js, glob

I am using mocha for testing. I am running mocha with a recursive glob pattern (`./src/**/*.test.ts`) to run all my tests, but only some of them are executed. Particularly only my tests under `src/utils` are being run. If I give mocha `./src/handlers/**/*.test.ts` as the path the tests do execute under `src/handlers`, but obviously this is not ideal.

I have done some refactoring on my code and before that it worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

**My project structure looks like this:**

```
src
  |-handlers
  |    |-Connection
  |        |-tests
  |            |- handleConnection.test.ts
  |            |- handleDisconnection.test.ts
  |            |...
  |-utils
       |-utils.test.ts
       |...
```

**I am trying to run mocha with this npm script:**

```
"test": "mocha ./src/**/*.test.ts -r ts-node/register"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around some more I have solved my issue by putting the glob pattern between single quotes:

```
"test": "mocha './src/**/*.test.ts' -r ts-node/register"
```

Apparently without putting it between quotes some systems can interpret ** as *:
[How can mocha recursively search my `src` folder for a specific filename pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005580/how-can-mocha-recursively-search-my-src-folder-for-a-specific-filename-pattern)