# Execute only one test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am working on a Node.js backend application that uses mocha to run unit and integration tests.
As seen [here](https://gist.github.com/timoxley/1721593) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005580/how-can-mocha-recursively-search-my-src-folder-for-a-specific-filename-pattern) (and many other that I do not post here but all say the same) I have the following test script:

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "eslint .",
    "test": "mocha --recursive \"tests/**/*.js\""
}
```

Tests are arranged as follow :

```
tests
  |_integration
  |   |_endpoint1
  |   |    |_test-endpoint.js
  |_unit
  |   |_components
  |   |    |_test_component1.js
  |   |    |_....
  |   |_services
  |   |    |_test-service1.js
  |   |    |_test-service2.js
  |   |    |_....
  |.....
```

When I run the `npm test` command mocha runs only test-service2.js and stops.

I am currently working on Mac with zsh as shell.

Comment: `"test": "mocha --require test-setup.js './**/*.spec.js'"` such approach seems more reasonable for me. Test files should not have a different file type such as `.spec.js`

Comment: its hard to say without seeing the contents of the test-service1.js. Might be the case the runner is not able to detect any test-suite or test cases in that file and hence it runs just one file

Comment: Thx for your hint @BrijeshPrasad I removed the test-service1.js file and all other tests seems to run. What bother me is that the tests written in the test-service1.js file are run and successfull. I'll check for other problems.